# Progressbar from Kendo UI don't work when I create it

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, progress-bar

I have some problem with Kendo UI. When I create a kendo progressbar it did't start. But when i use jQuery function .html() on DOM object, it start and throw me exception "pb[0].html is not a function".

Here is a code: http://dojo.telerik.com/aXEl/4

Someone see what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found a bug. In function "sendTicketAction" I refresh view and remove this